# git - temporary commit function to pass code snippet to other user?

Tags: git, temporary-files

I have a web project with a second developer. My part is doing the HTML+CSS+JS stuff, and my buddy writes the PHP+MySQL scripts.

So, mostly I prepare forms and the design of the page (and do the javascript stuff when needed). However, in order to work properly the other developer has to connect the forms I created with php to the database.

Is there an easier way instead of doing 2 commits (1. "html created" + push. other developer has to pull, commit "php added" and push it back)? Like passing the files to the other developer - an he just commits all files? Maybe something like doing a temporary commit, so that he can take it, modify the files, and push it all together...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd prefer the workflow you described since it's consistent:

- you add some functionality (create HTML)
- you push your current state
- your buddy adds his functionality (add PHP)
- your buddy pushes his current state

Of course, you won't do all that on the `master` branch. Create a `devel/whateverfeature` branch, work on that, once you finished development, squash changes and merge them into `master`.

I cannot see any bad things with this workflow...

**However**, if you absolutely don't want to see the public your development process, you could share a branch between you and your fellow. Your fellow adds your working copy as remote, you add the other working copy as remote.

Once you finished your work, tell him to fetch changes from your machine.
Once she's finished her work, she tells you to fetch changes from her machine.

You could do that either manually or by using [`git request-pull`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull).

**Third option** would be exchanging patches like [Akash proposes in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21044584/520162). The advantage of sending patches is that neither you nor your fellow needs access to the machine of the other AND the commits never appear in the public.

But even in this case, I wouldn't create a temporary commit. Do a real one or do 10 real ones. Once you finished your work, ask [`git format-patch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) to create the patches for you that you want to hand over to your buddy. Assuming you produces 10 commits that your peer needs,

```
git format-patch HEAD~10
```

will create 10 patch files that you could simply send over by e-mail to your fellow. The patches get applied with [`git am`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-am) and your colleague will have YOUR COMMITS with YOUR COMMIT MESSAGES.

If you're more interested in different ways of working with different repos, have a read of the [**Distributed Git** section of the Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git). This covers different scenarios how to hand over commits to each other.

Comment: +1 - use branches and the repository, there is no reason to complicate matters. As alternative is `git format-patch` to create patch files of commits that can be mailed and applied with `git am`.

Comment: @Abizern I was writing about `format-patch` while you commented :-)

Comment: Not surprised - it's fairly obvious. I was going to write about it as well. This saves me the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can send him a patch.

Lets say you have done some work and have not committed it. Create a patch file as follows:

```
git diff > myfirst.patch
```

Now send this patch file to the other developer. He can apply all your changes as:

```
git apply myfirst.patch
```

It is as easy as that. Once he commits and pushes his code, you can simply discard your changes by `git reset --hard` and do a `git pull` which will contain his changes and the changes from the patch you sent.

Although I recommend this flow only to be used occasionally. Git branches are generally a much more efficient and robust method of collaborating.

Answer (score 0):

You should use branches for achieve that.
Once you've completed html stuff, you should push to a branch. Then, your fellow pulls this branch, complete the php functionality and once both php+style is working, merge the branch into the master revision.

Read some general article for git and branches, I think that branching is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it to be one commit, you can always fork it to a separate branch. Make your commits, push it to your remote Git repository, have the other person pull it and make their commit, then rebase it on the original branch you started with.

For example, assuming you're on the master branch:

```
git checkout -b devel
git commit -am "Your commit message"
git push remote devel
# They make their changes and push
git pull
git rebase -i master
```

When you run `git rebase -i master`, Git will explain what to do. Most people choose to use "fixup" if they want to squash 2 commits.

So, say you have two commits. They would look like:

```
pick <commit id> <commit message>
pick <commit id> <commit message>
```

Most choose to do:

```
pick <commit id> <commit message>
f <commit id> <commit message>
```

`f` is short for "fixup". As mentioned, that will be explained when you `git rebase -i master`.

Unfortunately, this is as easy as it gets unless your other person wants to do the `git commit --fixup` themselves.